# Preference GUI in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have some code that draws a grid. I am looking to add on code that updates the line spacing of the grid depending on the user input.

Ideally, I would like to have a input box to type the grid spacing into, a draw button, and a hide button.

Here's what I have so far -

```
void Lines::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    int lineSpacing(30),// line spacing in pixels
            numberOfLines;
    int HEIGHT(500),
            WIDTH(600);

    QPen pen(Qt::black, 2, Qt::SolidLine);

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.setPen(pen);

    //Grid takes up at most a 400x400 area starting at (right 150, down 50) from upper left
    numberOfLines = 400/lineSpacing; //Round down grid size to fit in 400x400
    for(int i = 0; i<numberOfLines; i++){
        painter.drawLine(150, 50+i*lineSpacing, 150+(numberOfLines-1)*lineSpacing, 50+i*lineSpacing);
        painter.drawLine(150+i*lineSpacing, 50, 150+i*lineSpacing, 50+(numberOfLines-1)*lineSpacing );
    }
}
```

How do I make an input box for the user to modify the grid spacing?

Comment: How do I make an input box for the user to modify the grid spacing?

Comment: Well, by adding an input box (QSpinBox?) and using it?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can add a combo box or lineedit in your GUI and change the Grid spacing variable on the on_click event of corresponding widget.

for ex if its combo_box

```
void Lines:::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    lineSpacing=//change according to index variable as you wish
}
```

And also initialize linespacing and other variables in your constructor instead of Paintevent.